# AngularJS refresh view after send comment

Tags: angularjs

I created controller in AngularJS to display and send comment to my rest endpiont. How to refresh comment list after user click and send comment?

My controller:

```
.controller('CommentController',
    function($scope, $routeParams, NewsModel){

      var newsId = $routeParams.id;
      path = 'getCommetnsByNewsId/'+newsId;

      var comm = this;

      var data = new Date().toLocaleString();

      $scope.createComm = function(comment){
        NewsModel.createComment(angular.extend({},
          {data: data, newsId: newsId}, comment)).then(function (result){
          initCreateComm();

        })
      }
      function initCreateComm(){
        comm.newComm = { comment: '', author: ''};
      }

      NewsModel.getCommentById().then(function (result){
        $scope.comments = result.data;
        console.log($scope.comments);
      });

    })
```

Service:

```
.service('NewsModel', function($http, ENDPOINT_URI){

    var service = this;

    function getUrl(){
      return ENDPOINT_URI + path;
    }

    service.all = function(){
      return $http.get(getUrl());
    }

    service.getCommentById = function(){
      return $http.get(getUrl());
    }

    service.createComment = function(comment){
      return $http.post(getUrl(),comment);
    }

  });
```

And HTML:

```
<!-- Comments Form -->
  <div class="well">
    <h4>Leave comment:</h4>
    <form role="form" ng-submit="createComm(newComment)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newComment.author"  placeholder="Autor">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="newComment.comment" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Wyślij</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <hr>


  <div ng-repeat="comm in comments">

  <div class="media">

    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">{{comm.author}}
        <small>{{comm.data}}</small>
      </h4>
      {{comm.comment}}
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get the comments:

```
NewsModel.getCommentById().then(function (result){
    $scope.comments = result.data;
    console.log($scope.comments);
});
```

So you need to wrap it in a function and call it after adding a new comment:

```
$scope.getComments = function() {
    NewsModel.getCommentById().then(function (result){
        $scope.comments = result.data;
        console.log($scope.comments);
    });
};
$scope.getComments(); // Init the comments as the controller loades
```

And add this at the end of `$scope.createComm = function(comment){`:

```
$scope.createComm = function(comment){
    NewsModel.createComment(angular.extend({},
      {data: data, newsId: newsId}, comment)).then(function (result){
      initCreateComm();
      $scope.getComments(); // Update comments
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call your server to retrieve all the comments when you need to refresh comments list.

```
function fetchComments(){
    NewsModel.all().then(function(res){
        $scope.comments = res;
    });
}
```

and then call fetchComments() whenever you want to update the comments.